# odoo allocation request by employee tag validation error?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

Hello all I'am working on leaves conditions module in version 10 , I added a validation that raise when no joining date assigned to the employee , it;s working well,

But it's also raise while requesting allocation by employee tag , although I am tried a tag with only one employee in this tag and I am assigned a joining date for him
Here is the code

```
@api.constrains('state', 'date_from', 'holiday_status_id',)
def _check_hire_date(self):

     from_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.date_from)
     to_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.date_to)
     if self.employee_id.joining_date:
         jo_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.employee_id.joining_date)
     else:
         raise ValidationError("you must define joining date")
```

What should I do to pass all the validations that i'll do while allocation request and make it work just only while leaves requesting not allocations

Comment: what are you getting in from_dt and to_dt ?

Comment: there is some validations error that depend on them but i'am copy the related part of the code

Comment: I think this is wrong, you can't get values such as you coded. Please have a look at the documentations regarding the same.

Comment: You will find a good solution in your own, just keep trying good luck

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya what is wrong you see in my code ??

Comment: @CharifDZ i'am tried alot but the leaves and allocation in the same model with 2 views

Comment: @MohamedFouad, you just need to take that values from self it self, please have a look at here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#model-constraints

from_dt = self.from_dt

Comment: do you have a solution to solve my issue and igonring the 2 date field

Comment: Actually the thing is I'm not getting your question. please try to explain in correct way

Comment: @MohamedFouad you don't vote or accept answers that helped you, but I'm going to give you a hint that will help you, there is a field in the leave type witch distinctes the leaves from allocation just look for it,  and you sude use api.one with constraint because you didn't loop over self witch can cause you singleton error good luck

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya i need thr validation to take place only when requesting for a leave and pass the validation if the request for allocation

Comment: @CharifDZ you deleted your answer in my last qustion before otherwise it was correct one before i'am testing it to be voted up , thanks for your help dear , can you tell me the trick on my current issue

Comment: api.constrains triggers only when you try to save something. you can stop user if he's not having enough credits / or not fulfilling the criteria. you can use api.onchange ('Leave_Field')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field that you know if this is a leave or an allocation is `type`

```
     type = fields.Selection([
        ('remove', 'Leave Request'),
        ('add', 'Allocation Request')
    ],....)
```

So before starting validation check if it's not an allocation request :

```
      @api.one # because you didn't loop over self in your code
      @api.constrains('state', 'date_from', 'holiday_status_id',)
      def _check_hire_date(self):
              if self.type == 'add': return  # skip allocation requests
              # rest of your code goes
```